# how to delete songs which had received from an application named share it

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore, iphone

i have received some songs from android phone to iPhone 6 through an application named share it.I can't see those songs in music,but I can see these songs in share it application,even I can play it!! now I wanna delete those songs because these songs took 5gb of disk space! and we all know how important iPhones memory is ?? so help me out in deleting songs and make some memory free !!

Answer (score 1):

This is an application-specific question regarding the app "Share It!", which I do not know myself.  However, as with many applications, especially those promoting sharing, you may find an option to add or remove contents from within iTunes.

iTunes on the computer:

1. open iTunes
2. connect your iPhone 6
3. click on the device inside iTunes and navigate to the Apps section
4. on the right-hand side (where you see the iPhone screens with your apps placed), scroll down (there is a file sharing section)
5. check if "Share It!" is on the left hand side and if it is, click it
6. the songs should then be on the right-hand side and you can either simply remove them (hitting Backspace (Mac) or Delete (Windows) should take care of that) or export/import them to your computer

In-App:

You can also check, if you can remove the songs from within the app.  A lot of apps capable of receiving or creating user content have options to remove such items from within the app itself.  Check if you have an "Edit" option or similar when displaying the songs inside "Share It!" and once in that mode, see if you can select and remove songs.  If no such option is there, try swiping a song from right-to left and see, if a red "Delete" option reveals itself.

In case all of the above options fail, you can always remove the app entirely and then re-install it from the App Store free of charge.  Every time you remove an app, it will remove its settings and contents with it.  Therefore, this can be used as a last resort any time.

Answer (score 1):

Open shareit app and on the home screen you will see an option “My files”. (Just below the ‘receive’ option.)

There you will find files that you received through shareit arranged in different folders based on their file type.

Answer (score -1):

Just need to go at share it app at bottom you will find two options select the second one named FILES just open it select the folder you want to delete by tapping+holding for coiple of seconds a popup for deleting will appear if not then open desired folder and repeat the process to delete one by one.

Comment: This answer isn't very clear, please consider adding some punctuation. New lines, and bullet points to make the answer clearer.